# Where can I find 64bit Ubuntu OS Image for Intel core i5 processor?

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop

I searched in ubuntu.com portal but I dont see any where about the OS image for
my 64bit Intel Core i5 processor. where can I get this ? or can I use AMD64 or i386?

Comment: amd64 is for intel based 64-bit cpu. this includes AMD and INTEL processors.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use the AMD64 image.